# `dd`command: ISO to USB Changes Partition Table to APM

Tags: command-line, usb

I am trying to dd an ISO to a USB so I can install Linux on another computer, but the USB changes from any partition table (GPM or MBR) to APM when it finishes.

I'm using the following command:

```
sudo dd if=[path of iso] of=/dev/disk2
```

The command "diskutil list" successfully shows the usb is /dev/disk2 and Disk Utility shows the partition table before has changed to APM.

I've worked with dd and Disk Utility several times in the past and have never until now had this problem. I believe it changed after I upgraded from OS X to macOS.

APM is not able to be used on this computer so the ISO on the USB can't be read. Help?

Comment: You are probably dd'ing a hybrid disc. It contains an ISO prim vol descriptor as well as an APM. Please add a link to the iso (Ubuntu?)!

Comment: It doesn't matter what the partition table of the USB is, just make sure it's not mounted prior to using `dd`. The partition table of the USB will be whatever the ISO image is, as it's whats being written to the USB drive.

Comment: @klanomath I'm using the standard fedora 25 workstation and tried the same with qubes. I'm going to try the same with debian just for a test later tonight

Comment: @user3439894 it does when there aren't software drivers to work with APM and MBR is needed

Comment: @Noob101, You're missing the point, the USB will be partitioned however the ISO Image is laid out. If it's layout it not compatible with the Hardware it going to be run from then you need to get an ISO Image that's compatible!

Comment: @user3439894 So are you saying the iso determines the partition table or the partition table is negligible no matter what?

Comment: @Noob101, The layout of the ISO Image is the governing factor because after all it's the ISO Image that's being written to the USB drive. So, whatever currently exists on the USB drive is totally irrelevant as it's overwritten by the ISO Image by what `dd` is doing. Which is writing the ISO Image directly to, in this case `/dev/disk2`. It is not then intended to be mounted under macOS but booted on compatible hardware!

Comment: @user3439894 So then why would a standard iso for both qubes, fedora, and debian all have an APM partitiion map then? It seems that it would be more logical to ship with GPT or MBR

Comment: @Noob101, Look, you haven't yet provided the exact name of the ISO Image or a link for us to download and examine it, so I can't comment since I don't have the Image to examine! Although I do have to say I'm not sure I want to waste the bandwidth downloading an ISO I'll never use! FWIW I will say that I have no problem downloading and ISO Image of Linux Mint, writing it to USB with `dd`, and then booting from the USB to install Linux Mint onto a PC.

Comment: @Noob101 Check the iso with `hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso` (<- choose the proper path to the image here), then `hdiutil info` and /or  `hdiutil fsid ~/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso` (<- choose the proper path to the image here) and you will see that it is a hybrid disk!

Comment: @user3439894 I actually stated above that they were standard isos of debian, fedora, and qubes. I can try more isos but I doubt this will do anything. The specific name of each iso are "debian-9.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso" and "Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso" with both having the same situation. The link to qubes is right at qubes-os.org. There is nothing special about these images. I highly doubt that APM is the fault of an iso that everyone and there mother uses. Why are you get pissed at me for detailing what was asked? Also, I never said Linux Mint.

Comment: @klanomath After the hdiutil attach, I got "hdiutil: attach failed - image not recognized" so I was not able to complete this. And yes, I used the correct file path.

Comment: Did you crc/md5/sha256 the file [Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso](http://ftp.uci.edu/fedora/linux/releases/25/Workstation/x86_64/iso/)?

Comment: @klanomath Yep, I got "818017f42a2741cfaf20e94aecf6a63d1b995abfdaff5917df7218d0d89976a7"

Comment: I'll try using dd on another machine later this afternoon once I get home.

Comment: @Noob101, Okay, I downloaded the Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso image, verified its SHA256 checksum, used `dd` to write it to a USB Flash Drive and then booted a PC from it to the Live Desktop of Fedora Workstation, and tested the OS out. The only thing I had to do, was press Esc at the start of the integrity test, as it fails for some reason otherwise. It's absolutely totally irrelevant that an APM is created, because it's supposed to be there! The Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-25-1.3.iso image is a Hybrid ISO Image with a GPT and APM and it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: @Noob101, So, what's the real problem here!? Can you not boot a system from the USB you `dd`ed the image to?

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the disk device, not a partition on it, so yes, some chunk of the data from the ISO is going to overwrite the partition table on your USB device.

You don't provide enough details to determine anything else.

Comment: So then I just dd to the partition? and what information am I leaving out?

Comment: @Noob101 No, the ISO 9660 volume header has to be in the raw disk, not in a partition. An ISO 9660 disk has no partition table (unless it's some sort of hybrid format).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Well I'm not using a partition. /dev/disk2 is the over arching device, not the device partition. So the question remains of why I get APM. If I was dding to something like /dev/disk2s1, then I would agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve this issue on my macbook and used some else's mac instead. I have no idea why it works on theirs but not mine. Very mysterious...